# Four color theorem for 'solid' maps

Tags: geometry, coloring

Is there an equivalent of the four color theorem for 'solid' maps? In other words, if we consider a 'map' in $3D$ what is the minimum number of colors we have to use in order to avoid that two adiacent solid regions have the same color?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that we can produce $n$ regions so that any two are "adjacent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

André's comment is correct: for any integer $n>0$ it is possible to produce a collection of $n$ solid regions each of which touches all the others. The solid regions to be constructed are best explained by a picture, but I don't want to put in the effort, so here's a description. The $n$ regions, $R_i$, for $0<i<n$ are all constructed in a similar way:

1. Take two sticks each with unit square cross-sections and length $n$ units.
2. Lay one stick perpendicularly on top of the other, so they form a cross.
3. The lower stick will project $i$ units in front of the crossing stick and the crossing stick similarly projects $i$ units to the left of the lower stick.

Now take the $n$ regions and lay them out in left-to-right order $R_0, R_1, \dotsc, R_{n-1}$, arranged so that the lower stick of each is aligned in the front.

You'll then have $n$ regions, each of which touches all the rest. In short, there's no minimum chromatic number for solid regions in 3-space. An interesting followup: what if we required the regions to be convex?.

Comment: Extend the basic triangle surrounded by three mutually-touching regions to a tetrahedron surrounded by four mutually-touching blocks. All five are convex, so you need at least five. Assume a [spherical tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) with any number of blocks touching it, and the surface generalizes to the four-color theorem.  So I'll bet 5 is the maximum.